# Meaning of 引きよせられるように

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for some help understanding what 引きよせられるように means in the below.

I understand そっと胸の中へ包み込んだ to mean that he gently embraced 茉莉愛 into his chest, but I'm not quite sure how 引きよせられるように modifies this. Does this sort of give the impression/idea that she was "pulled" towards him?

俺を見つめる茉莉愛。**引きよせられるように**、そっと胸の中へ包み込んだ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of 包み込んだ is clearly 俺, so the subject of 引き寄せられる should be 俺, too. So this 引き寄せられるように means not "pulling her into my arms" but "(I was) being (psychologically) pulled to her" or "being allured by her".